# ActiveDirectory DirectorySearcher with / in the user or group name resulting error 0x80005000L

Tags: c#, .net

I am using below code to search `Active Directory` and work perfectly ok expect for ones with / the user or group name resulting `error 0x80005000L`.

```
DirectorySearcher vDirectorySearcher = null;
DirectoryEntry vDirectoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP...");
vDirectorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher (vDirectoryEntry);
vDirectorySearcher.Sort = new SortOption ("name", SortDirection.Ascending);
vDirectorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Group)(CN-" + groupName +));
SearchResultCollection req;
req = vDirectorySearcher.FindAll();
ResultPropertyValueCollection propValues = req [0]. Properties ["distinguishedName"];
// ...
```

How can I fix this, please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: Escape it: `groupName.Replace("/", @"\/")`

Comment: perfect, thank you. What does this code mean?

Comment: It just replaces all instances of `/` with the escape sequence `\/` - which is how ADSI expects you to escape forward slashes in DN's (including RDN values) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP doesn't care about `/`, but ADSI (the service abstraction layer through which `DirectorySearcher` talks to the LDAP service on a DC) needs them escaped with a simple backslash:

```
vDirectorySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Group)(CN-" + groupName.Replace("/", @"\/") + "))";
```